# Ascertaining a mathematical equality to derive a partition function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, mathematics, partition-function

we have an equation like this:

$$\mathcal N(x)=\sum_{q=1}^\infty (\psi(x,q) \log(q)) \qquad (1)$$

while $\psi(x)$ is the function for some oscillations (may contain complex part), $x\in \Bbb R$ and $q \in \Bbb N$.

It is further ensured that:

$$ \mathcal N(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    x & \quad \text{if $x\in \Bbb N$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$$

I need your help, even if it sounds simple, **whether the following equality is mathematically correct**:

$$n^{-\psi^*}=\mathcal N(n)^{-\psi(n,q)}$$

with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\psi^*=\psi(n,q)$.

I would really appreciate your help. I need this for constructing a partition function.

**If the above equality as such is not correct, how is the correct formalism?**

Comment: The second part about $\mathcal{N}(x)$ doesn't make sense. What is $n$, where does it come from?

Comment: the second part looks trivial but is true. See the first two equations as a spectrum of particles $\mathcal N$ points then to the location of the particles which is exactly the location of positive integers on real number line. The second equation is implicit in the first. Does thta help?

Comment: @Raskolnikov imagine $\mathcal N$ as a Fourier that points out the natural numbers.

Comment: I've made some edits. But it now seems to me your expression is trivially true.

Comment: Dear al-Hwarizmi, the Fourier transform of your function that is zero almost everywhere yet finite is zero. To get a nontrivial function in the L2 or Fourier sense, you would have to have delta-functions located at the integer values of $x$, like $\sum_k k\delta(x-k)$, not just a finite value.

Comment: delta sums is one possibility, Shah is another way, there are other possibilities dependent on what you want to connect the formula to, I have a variety of them. What $\mathcal N$ could be is less relevant, my question is how we put a function to exponent and inverse instead of each of the individual number $n$... How would the zeta function or Chebychev function for $\mathcal N$ look like?

Comment: @LubošMotl you brough me to a great idea! I can simulate at least the functions with an discrete input function. That helps at least to get an imagination what happens! Thanks